# Spring SpEL not compiling even when spring.expression.compiler.mode is set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a SpEL expression that I am trying to use for an FtpMessageHandler (specifically for `outputHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("headers['" + ftpOutPath + "']");`).

Through debugging I have found that this SpEL expression is not getting compiled. When compilation time comes, `SpelCompilerMode` is set to `OFF`. So as a result the expression is not being compiled and just returning `null` (and my FTP client is trying to just write to the root directory instead of the one I am specifying).

Looking at the Spring SpEL documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) , it says that in order to enable SpEL compilation you need to set the property `spring.expression.compiler.mode`. I have done this to no effect - I have set `spring.expression.compiler.mode` to `immediate` in my application.properties file, yet `SpelCompilerMode` is still `OFF`.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

I know someone will ask for a code sample but honestly I have no idea what I can provide as this is all stuff internal to Spring. But here are some samples of related code:

The FtpMessageHandler:

```
    @Value("${my.ftp.outPath}")
    private String ftpOutPath;

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
    public MessageHandler getOutputHandle(){
        FtpMessageHandler outputHandler = new FtpMessageHandler(mySessionFactory());
        outputHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("headers['" + ftpOutPath + "']");
        return outputHandler;
    }
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  expression:
    compiler:
      mode: immediate

my:
  ftp:
    outPath: myPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure why the expression was not compiling / intrepreting properly, however changing the code to use `LiteralExpression` worked instead of using the String.

`outputHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(ftpOutPath));`